# iPhone (iOS) app (difficulty on creating)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ipod

I have a quick question about iOS apps and was wondering maybe someone here could help me out with an answer... Just curious to know, how hard would it be to create a very very simple iOS app that would lets say just have maybe a start up screen (if even necessary) and then one main screen that would change every day (obviously the creator would be changing it every day as a daily update and it would refresh on each person app)

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your experience. The biggest unknown factor is the daily update. There are many ways you could do this. Did you have anything in mind?

Comment: Not sure exactly... I have never worked with an online type of app before... Anything I have done has been simple apps or games regular desktop based...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know objective c basic then no problem occur in develop that kind of App.Read some basic of that language and you easily develop an App. Read about object,array,pointers,memory management and syntax of that topics is must for develop an iOS App.

Comment: Hmmm ok thank you... Yes I have done tutorials before on Objective-C but haven't in a while... Was just curious to know how much knowledge I would need to have something like that ... Thanks!

Comment: was going to.... had to wait a few minutes